# Filtered text query

Tags: text, filter, elasticsearch

I am doing the following query in elasticsearch:
`{"size":20000,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{match_all:{}},"filter":{"or":[{"term":{CATEGORY:"diamonds"}},{"term":{CATEGORY:"fashion"}}]}}}}`

This works fine. What I need now is that the `CATEGORY` has names such as `Men Clothing` and `Men Accessories`. So I want to do a text query. But when I replaced term with `text`, it didnt work for me. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just had to index the CATEGORY as not_analyzed and then run a term query. It worked.